# SpoolDirectory to Hbase using Flume

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hbase, flume, flume-ng

I am able to perform the operation of transferring my data from spooldir to Hbase, but my data is in Json Format and I want them to be in separate columns. I am using Kafka channel.
P.F.A attached the photo of my hbase column

If you notice in the picture status, category, sub_category should be different columns.
I created HBASE table like this - create 'table_name','details'. So, they are in same column family but how do I segregate json data to different columns? Any thoughts?
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using Spark Streaming or Nifi for this? To my knowledge, Flume cannot parse JSON

Comment: I am not good at spark streaming, I can transfer my data to hbase using spark streaming?

Comment: HBase has a Java API, so yes.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will check

Comment: To clarify, getting the data into  Kafka is fine. From there, there are multiple ways to get it out, but you'll need some parsing logic between reading that data and putting into the database